# Slice 3d-tensor-based dataset into smaller tensor lengths

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I have a dataset for training networks, formed out of two tensors, my features and my labels. The shape of my demonstration set is [351, 4, 34] for features, and [351] for labels.

Now, I would like to re-shape the dataset into chunks of size k (ideally while loading data with DataLoader), to obtain a new demonstration set for features of shape [351 * n, 4, k] and the corresponding label shape [351 * n], with n = floor(34 / k). The main aim is to reduce the length of each feature, to decrease the size of my network afterwards.

As written example: Starting from

```
t = [[1, 2, 3, 4], 
     [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

i.e. a `[2, 4]`-tensor, with

```
l = [1, 0]
```

as labels, I would like to be able to go to (with k = 2)

```
t = [[1, 2], 
     [3, 4], 
     [5, 6], 
     [7, 8]]
l = [1, 1, 0, 0]
```

or to (with k = 3)

```
t = [[1, 2, 3], 
     [5, 6, 7]]
l = [1, 0]
```

I found some solutions for reshaping one of the tensors (by using variations of `split()`), but then I would have to transfer that to my other tensor, too, and therefore I'd prefer solutions inside my DataLoader instead.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reshape the input to the desired shape (first dimension is `n` times longer) while the label can be repeated with [`torch.repeat_interleave`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.repeat_interleave.html#torch.repeat_interleave).

```
def split(x, y, k=2):
    n = floor(x.size(1) / k)
    x_ = x.reshape(len(x)*n, -1)[:,:k]
    y_ = y.repeat_interleave(len(x_)//len(y))
    return x_, y_
```

You can test it like so:

```
>>> split(t, l, k=2)
(tensor([[1, 2],
         [3, 4],
         [5, 6],
         [7, 8]]), tensor([1, 1, 0, 0]))

>>> split(t, l, k=3)
(tensor([[1, 2, 3],
         [5, 6, 7]]), tensor([1, 0]))
```

*I recommend doing this kind of processing in your dataset class.*

Comment: Just one question: What is `t` in line 3 in `split()`? Is it an artefact from testing, or does it refer to `t` in my question?

Comment: Sorry, it is indeed `x`, the input of the function, not `t` ;)

Comment: Except the output for the second case is faulty, it does not correspond with what I would expect. The first case works fine, thanks!

Comment: Can you detail why this is the expected result for `k=3`?

Comment: If I set my length to three, I would expect the maximum length of my tensor to be three, not four. As I can not create a second tensor with the same length (as 4 // 3 == 1), wanted to drop the last entry. At the same time my label tensor gets bigger (from len(l)==2 to len(l)==6, even though I do not increase the number of data correspondingly (I still have two sets of data, not six). That's what confuses me with the proposed solution.

Comment: Ok, could you please provide the shape of the returned input tensor function of `k`?

Comment: As in my example above, t.shape would go from [2, 4] to [2, 3], and l.shape stays for k = 3. For k = 2 t.shape would go from [2, 4] to [4, 2], and l.shape from [2] to [4]